# How can I type php instead of /usr/local/php5/bin/php?

Tags: linux, bash

Now I have to type `/usr/local/php5/bin/php` to run `php`,

is there a way so that I just type `php` and it's run?

Answer (score 2):

you can either add an alias to your ~/.bash_profile file like so(http://freeunix.dyndns.org:8088/site2/howto/Bash.shtml):

```
 alias php=/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

for this i recommend using something else other than php though unless its the only php binary on your system

or you can either Symlink the to the php binary in /usr/local/php5/bin from /usr/sbin

```
ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/sbin/php
```

or add the directory to your PATH environment by editing or adding the following line in your ~/.bashrc file (you need to logout and in for this to work)

```
PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:${PATH}
```

options 1 and 3 are only for your user, if you need it to work for all users of the system you need to use option 2

Comment: Despite the massive comments on the other answer, yours is complete and has good explanations.  One thing to note is that setting the PATH will introduce ordering if there's another `php` binary somewhere on his system (i.e., /usr/bin/php).  Whichever path appears first will be used.

Comment: Please try to show the users the right path of doing that. Is not useful if on 3 weeks after an upgrade your solutions will not work. All 3 solutions from here will work, but only the PATH solution is 100% safe.

Comment: For the ordering of php binaries, type `type -a php` to see them all.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/sbin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php
sudo chmod +x php
```

Comment: Is not the good answer. It will work, but in future is possible to have problems when you try to install a real php5 distro and you will not know why is not working.

Comment: /usr/local/php5/bin/php  means it was compiled from source. or im just one who uses /usr/local/blabla for source compiled programs. 
and .bashrc path wont work for zsh shell or some other )

Comment: Is compiled from sources, or are the third party binaries. This is the reason why is not a good idea to link in /usr/sbin. We should maintain clean system, to don't break the packages what are possible to come in the future. If is using zsh then it should use .zshrc, but the systems by default are coming with bash and not zsh.

Comment: hence why you use a symlink rather than placing the binary there.... it should get overwritten/replaced if you happen to install a binary package of something you have compiled from source (which is a very rare event because people compiling from source are less likely to be installing it from a binary down the line)

Comment: Every good package manager will not replace the symlink! It will crash and tell you there is a file which shouldn't be. As I said is not a solution, a good solution is to link in /usr/local/sbin or use stow.

Comment: @Sacx if this source-package was installed for some program or is used somewhere else in script, the configuration files of those programs shoud be updated with php-Path. And if some script is using this php
variable PATH shoud be updated either. Often programs or scripts uses command "which" and puts its answer to PATH-to-PHP.

Comment: IF if if if ... we are talking without know what is in the system. Linking is /usr/sbin by hand is not a good solution. It will work, but is not a good solution.

Comment: @Sacx. Okey. Youve got /usr/bin/php and /usr/local/bin/php and have got them both at PATH. what php would executed?

Comment: the first one what is in the path, and usually is /usr/bin. don't do symlinks by hand. You can use stow, update-alternatives etc etc, but, as I said, doing that by hand is dangerous for a new guy.

Comment: okey. we know too much for this question :D

Comment: we should start flaming on real questions :)

Answer (score 0):

add in your .bashrc

```
PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:${PATH}
```

logout and login again.

Answer (score -1):

You can add /usr/local/php5/bin to your PATH, or you can make an alias